# Returning Current Index of input group via JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Houston we have a situation.. Any light would be greatly appreciated.

Hard to explain but will do my best. Did my homework but could not get it solved. Have the code similar to the following. (Static, hard to change. Need to find a solution to the existing structure.).

The array in question is grade[].

```
(line 1)  \<input id='grade[]'  onclick="curr_ndx(this);" \>   // index of grade[] is 0
(line 2)  \<input id='grade[]'  onclick="curr_ndx(this);" \>   // index of grade[] is 1
(line 3)  \<input id='grade[]'  onclick="curr_ndx(this);" \>   // index of grade[] is 2
```

I need to retrieve the index of 'grade[]' of the the input within array of 'grade[]'. If user clicks on 'input' of line 2, it should alert '1', or, '2' if user clicks on (line 3 input).

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Ids should be unique, since these are input I suggest changing from ids to name attributes.

Comment: u need to provide some unique id to all the input elements and obviously in your case it can be the index and onclick u can return the id having the index. `id's are unique u cannot have multiple id's of same name`

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you can use the `.index()` method to find out which sibling a given item is like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="grades">
<input \>
<input \>
<input \>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$("#grades input").click(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xvVGx/

FYI, you should also not have duplicate id values on your input fields.  Perhaps you meant to be using `name='grade[]'` instead of `id='grade[]'`.

---

If you have other input fields and you want to only count the `id='grade[]'` ones, then you can do this:

```
$("#grades input").click(function() {
    alert($(this).index("[id*='grade[]']"));
});
```

---

But, you really shouldn't have duplicate id values, so it should probably be this:

HTML:

```
<div id="grades">
<input name='grade[]' \>
<input name='grade[]' \>
<input name='grade[]' \>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$("#grades input[name='grade[]']").click(function() {
    alert($(this).index("[name='grade[]']"));
});
```

Comment: But will that filter same-named inputs from others? Seems to me the OP has confused ID and NAME attributes.

Comment: @RobG - The OP did not suggest that there was a complication like that so I didn't try to solve for one.  That's why I put these input tags inside a containing div in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery `index()` http://api.jquery.com/index/.

```
$('input').click(function() {
  alert($(this).index());
})
```

Comment: It posts (-1) when I place "alert($(this).index());" right into onclick of each input. Just trivia. Not sure if that's the right way, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the elements all the same name, the function can be:

```
function curr_ndx(el) {
  var els = document.getElementsByName(el.name);
  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (els[i] == el) return i;
  }
}
```

If the elements are in a form, you can leverage that too:

```
function curr_ndx(el) {
  var els = el.form[el.name];
  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (els[i] == el) return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works awesome. You guys are great. Any of you be happen to be in Toronto, ON, beer is on me.